# Pandas dataframe how to assign value to a column basing on a specific group and previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
plane   Time    Time_difference
  1      180    0
  1      195    15
  1     3000    2805
  1     3100    100
  2     2323    0
  2     2665    342
```

I want to add a column of "trip" where if the Time_difference is more than 
500, it starts a new trip, trip count goes up by 1 and (if Time_difference is less than 500, trip number should be the same. 
The trip count should start at  1 again for  different planes

```
plane   Time  Time_difference  trip
  1      180     0             1
  1      195    15             1
  1     3000    2805           2
  1     3100    100            2
  2     2323    0              1     
  2     2665    342            1
```

i have tried the following, but the trip doesn't start back at 1 for different planes.

```
 def rollin(diff):
    if diff >= threshold:
       rollin.count += 1

    else:
      rollin.count 

    return rollin.count

 rollin.count = 0

 df2["trip"] = df2["Time_difference"].apply(rollin)
```

Comment: How did you calculate  the values `3100, 100` for the other two columns?

Comment: Do you only have 2 brackets - <500 and >=500?

Comment: @Jondiedoop sorry that was a mistake when copying it down, just fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a 'trip' column:

```
df['trip'] = 0
```

Then set the first row of each plane group to value 1.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('plane').head(1).index,'trip'] = 1
```

Then set any Time_difference > 500 for column 'trip' to 1

```
df.loc[df['Time_difference']>500, 'trip'] =1
```

Then cumsum by groupby 'plane'

```
df['trip'] = df.groupby('plane')['trip'].cumsum()

print(df)

  plane  Time  Time_difference  trip
0      1   180                0     1
1      1   195               15     1
2      1  3000             2805     2
3      1  3100              100     2
4      2  2323                0     1
5      2  2665              342     1
```